# page replacement algorithm

Tags: linux, memory

What is the name for the page replacement algorithm for 2.6 linux kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux calls it the "Page Frame Reclaiming Algorithm".

In my limited understanding, it's basically LRU with a bias towards non-dirty pages.

See [chapter 17 of Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/linux/0596005652/page-frame-reclaiming/understandlk-chp-17-sect-3#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTA1OTYwMDU2NTIvdW5kZXJzdGFuZGxrLUNIUC0xNw==) for more details.